# AjaxHelper.BeginForm всегда "нажимает" первую кнопку по Enter, а нужно вторую

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Имеется форма `@using (Ajax.BeginForm...` , на которой три кнопки `<button ...>`. При нажатии на `Enter`, автоматически выделяется самая первая кнопка и у нее вызывается click. Как сделать так, чтобы "кликалась" другая кнопка?

UPDATE: Важное пояснение: Клик по энтеру происходит из-за того, что тип у всех этих кнопок - submit (по-умолчанию).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

судя по [спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#implicit-submission) никак нельзя указать:

> A form element's default button is the first submit button in tree order whose form owner is that form element.

---

> Кнопкой по умолчанию для отправки формы является *первая* кнопка с типом *submit* для этой формы

Answer (score 0):

Пришлось использовать костыль на js:

```js
function setDefaultButton(formid, buttonid, excludeElements) {
    $("#" + formid).bind('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            for (var i = 0; i < excludeElements.length - 1 ; i++)
            {
                if ($(excludeElements[i]).is(':focus'))
                    return true;
            }

            $("#" + buttonid).focus();
            $("#" + buttonid).click();
            return false;
        };
    });
}
```